# Coming soon page used instead of home page

Tags: homepage

I am new in WordPress I have problem regarding coming soon page. I developed my hole one pager website and set my static page home also disable coming soon page (of hosting provider also) after that I done google indexing but when I search url my domain showing coming soon page I dont know where is this page set in wordpress Please help me to show my home page when i search my url.

Comment: Can you provide a url?

Comment: https://ddgroup.com.pk/ (not showing my Home page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your theme has some sort of maintenance mode - there is a CSS class on the `<body>` of `elementor-maintenance-mode`

Have a look at the documentation here: https://docs.elementor.com/article/194-maintenance-mode

Comment: Yeah buddy you solve my problem 'link' help me  (i go to elementor tools there i found coming soon page enable i disable) and i succeed I am very glad and thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please mark this as the accepted answer as it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a theme check the theme options. 
If you have a plugin check if you have disabled the mode before disabling the plugin. 
Check your htaccess file in the root folder if it contains anything else than the detail content between #Begin WordPress and #End WordPress.
Check if you have an index.html in the root folder of your website and delete it - note: do NOT delete index.php

Edit: You are new - so - it's always a good idea to backup anything before you delete or modify it!

Comment: I check my htaccess file and this is i found between  #Begin WordPress and #End WordPress  (<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: or i dont have index.html in root folder. Here my website look like right now  https://ddgroup.com.pk/ (not showing home page)

Comment: htaccess is good. No index HTML also. did you deactivate all active plugins and test it?

Comment: yes I deactivate coming soon plugin and any other but still my website look like https://ddgroup.com.pk/ you can see.